# How are Spring <task:scheduled> objects represented at runtime?

Tags: spring

I have an app that uses the "task:scheduler" and "task:scheduled-tasks" elements (the latter containing "task:scheduled" elements).  This is all working fine.

I'm trying to write some code that introspects the "application configuration" to get a short summary of some important information, like what tasks are scheduled and what their schedule is.

I already have a class that has a bunch of "@Autowired" instance variables so I can iterate through all of this.  It was easy enough to add a "List" to get all of the TaskScheduler objects.  I only have two of these, and I have a different set of scheduled tasks in each of them.

What I can't see in those TaskScheduler objects (they are actually ThreadPoolTaskScheduler objects) is anything that looks like a list of scheduled tasks, so I'm guessing the list of scheduled tasks is recorded somewhere else.

What objects can I use to introspect the set of scheduled tasks, and which thread pool they are in?

Answer (score 19):

This functionality will be available in Spring 4.2

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12748 (Disclaimer: I reported this issue and contributed code towards its solution).

```
// Warning there may be more than one ScheduledTaskRegistrar in your
// application context. If this is the case you can autowire a list of 
// ScheduledTaskRegistrar instead.
@Autowired   
private ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar; 

public List<Task> getScheduledTasks() {
    List<Task> result = new ArrayList<Task>();
    result.addAll(this.scheduledTaskRegistrar.getTriggerTaskList());
    result.addAll(this.scheduledTaskRegistrar.getCronTaskList());
    result.addAll(this.scheduledTaskRegistrar.getFixedRateTaskList());
    result.addAll(this.scheduledTaskRegistrar.getFixedDelayTaskList());
    return result;
}

// You can this inspect the tasks, 
// so for example a cron task can be inspected like this:

public List<CronTask> getScheduledCronTasks() {
    List<CronTask> cronTaskList = this.scheduledTaskRegistrar.getCronTaskList();
    for (CronTask cronTask : cronTaskList) {
        System.out.println(cronTask.getExpression);
    }
    return cronTaskList;
}
```

If you are using a ScheduledMethodRunnable defined in XML:

```
<task:scheduled method="run" cron="0 0 12 * * ?" ref="MyObject" />
```

You can access the underlying target object:

```
 ScheduledMethodRunnable scheduledMethodRunnable = (ScheduledMethodRunnable) task.getRunnable();
 TargetClass target = (TargetClass) scheduledMethodRunnable.getTarget();
```

Comment: Nice that scheduled tasks can now be inspected! Would your contributed code also make it possible to alter the trigger at runtime, e.g. change the rate of a fixed rate task from 1 to 2 seconds?

Comment: @Markus Are you able to elaborate on your intended use case so I can better understand the problem you are trying to solve? The Spring Scheduling task architecture is designed to be immutable. The intention is if you need to change the properties of a scheduled task then you will cancel the existing task and schedule a new one.

Comment: The interval in my application shall be configured from the user interface. Every x seconds a a task is executed to make some calculations. The task may run every 10 seconds for a while, later the user decides to run it every 5 seconds. Any type of task will do (e.g. a TriggerTask) as long as the interval can be changed at runtime.

Comment: This seems not to work when you use `@Scheduled` annotation, since the `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` is private and only meant to be available while `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is processing the annotations.

Comment: @ngeek I have submitted a PR to fix this, will see if it gets accepted. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/878 https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13506

Comment: @Markus at present this is not possible unless you want to use some reflection. I don't recommend doing this. You would need to obtain the Set<ScheduledFuture<?>> from the ScheduledTaskRegistrar and cancel the tasks. You would then need to obtain the TaskScheduler and schedule a new task.

Answer (score 4):

With `@Scheduled` based configuration the approach from Tobias M’s answer does not work out-of-the-box.

Instead of autowiring a `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` instance (which is not available for annotation based configuration), you can instead autowire a `ScheduledTaskHolder` which only has a `getScheduledTasks()` method.

Background:

The `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` used to manage `@Scheduled` tasks has an internal `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` that’s not available as a bean. It does implement `ScheduledTaskHolder`, though.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

Answer (score 3):

I have a snippet for pre spring 4.2 since it is still sitting at release candidate level.

The scheduledFuture interface is implemented by every runnable element in the BlockingQueue.

```
        Map<String, ThreadPoolTaskScheduler> schedulers = applicationContext
                .getBeansOfType(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.class);
        for (ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler : schedulers.values()) {
            ScheduledExecutorService exec = scheduler.getScheduledExecutor();
            ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor poolExec = scheduler
                    .getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor();
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = poolExec.getQueue();
            Iterator<Runnable> iter = queue.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                ScheduledFuture<?> future = (ScheduledFuture<?>) iter.next();
                future.getDelay(TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            Runnable job = iter.next();
            logger.debug(MessageFormat.format(":: Task Class is {0}", JobDiscoverer.findRealTask(job)));
            }
```

Heres a reflective way to get information about which job class is in the pool as *threadPoolNamePrefix* didn't return a distinct name for me:

```
public class JobDiscoverer {
    private final static Field syncInFutureTask;
    private final static Field callableInFutureTask;
    private static final Class<? extends Callable> adapterClass;
    private static final Field runnableInAdapter;
    private static Field reschedulingRunnable;
    private static Field targetScheduledMethod;

    static {
        try {

            reschedulingRunnable = Class
                    .forName(
                            "org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable")
                    .getDeclaredField("delegate");
            reschedulingRunnable.setAccessible(true);

            targetScheduledMethod = Class
                    .forName(
                            "org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable")
                    .getDeclaredField("target");
            targetScheduledMethod.setAccessible(true);
            callableInFutureTask = Class.forName(
                    "java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync").getDeclaredField(
                    "callable");
            callableInFutureTask.setAccessible(true);
            syncInFutureTask = FutureTask.class.getDeclaredField("sync");
            syncInFutureTask.setAccessible(true);

            adapterClass = Executors.callable(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                }
            }).getClass();
            runnableInAdapter = adapterClass.getDeclaredField("task");
            runnableInAdapter.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            throw new PiaRuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new PiaRuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Object findRealTask(Runnable task) {
        if (task instanceof FutureTask) {
            try {
                Object syncAble = syncInFutureTask.get(task);
                Object callable = callableInFutureTask.get(syncAble);
                if (adapterClass.isInstance(callable)) {
                    Object reschedulable = runnableInAdapter.get(callable);
                    Object targetable = reschedulingRunnable.get(reschedulable);
                    return targetScheduledMethod.get(targetable);
                } else {
                    return callable;
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }
        throw new ClassCastException("Not a FutureTask");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Spring XML element has a corresponding [`BeanDefinitionReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/BeanDefinitionParser.html). For `<task:scheduled-tasks>`, that's [`ScheduledTasksBeanDefinitionParser`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTasksBeanDefinitionParser.html).

This uses a `BeanDefinitionBuilder` to create a `BeanDefinition` for a bean of type [`ContextLifecycleScheduledTaskRegistrar`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ContextLifecycleScheduledTaskRegistrar.html). Your scheduled tasks will be stored in that bean.

The tasks will be executing in either a default `TaskScheduler` or one you provided.

I've given you the class names so you can look at the source code yourself if you need more fine grained details.

Comment: I don't see anything in the public interface of the ContextLifecycleScheduledTaskRegistrar class or the associated TaskScheduler class that will let me read this information.  I suppose I could resort to some serious reflection hacking, but that's obviously not ideal.

Comment: @David I don't have it in front of me, but check the Registrar's parent class.

Comment: I did.  That's ScheduledTaskRegistrar.  Nothing there I can use either.  Above that is Object.

Comment: @David Those lists of tasks aren't what you're looking for?

Comment: The list of tasks and their schedule is exactly what I'm looking for.  These classes provide an interface to add new tasks, but there is no public interface to list what tasks are scheduled.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr You're right, there isn't. The tasks are meant to be known to you, as you're the one who submit them. You'll have to use reflection if you want to retrieve them. Note that the `java.util.concurrent` classes don't have a retrieval mechanism either.