# How to get list of current running scheduled task / job in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have an spring boot app that uses spring job scheduling. I had followed [this sample](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-job-scheduling-with-scheduled-enablescheduling-annotations/).

Now the problem is how to get list of current running scheduler / job ? Currently i'm using spring boot 1.5.2 RELEASE.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017691/accessing-scheduled-tasks-in-spring

Answer (score 1):

Create an own **thread pool** and configure Spring to use that *thread pool* for executing all the *scheduled tasks*.

Follow this example:

```java
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

  private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

  @Override
  public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my-scheduled-task-pool-");
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

    scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.