# List Spring's @Scheduled Tasks

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I need to list scheduled and running tasks. I've been searching for a way to display that information in the front end, but I haven't had any luck with this.

Is there a way to do this?

Basically I need to

- Display Scheduled tasks
- Display currently running tasks
- Display any information relevant to scheduled tasks

EDIT 1: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017691/accessing-scheduled-tasks-in-spring) is a 6 years old answer and I was hoping to get a more up-to-date answer.

EDIT 2: This is not a Spring Boot project

EDIT 3: Currently using Spring 5.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: I saw the answer and it's from 2014, I was hoping a more up-to-date answer

Comment: Is this just Spring or Spring Boot? Spring Boot Actuator does have a `scheduledtasks` API that can give you some of what you want

Comment: Could you please specify the version of spring you are using ?

Comment: added Spring version as requested (5.1.1.RELEASE)

Answer (score 3):

You can access all scheduled tasks that were registered either programmatically or by the `@Scheduled` annotation by injecting `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and calling `getScheduledTasks()`.

```java
/**
 * Return all currently scheduled tasks, from {@link Scheduled} methods
 * as well as from programmatic {@link SchedulingConfigurer} interaction.
 * @since 5.0.2
 */
@Override
public Set<ScheduledTask> getScheduledTasks()
```

But from there it gets a bit tricky. In `ScheduledTask#getTask` it is pointed out that the returned `Task` can be of three different types. More precisely it can be `CronTask`, `FixedRateTask`or `FixedDelayTask` (and maybe in future releases others as well). So you need to be a bit creative here and test via `instanceof` which type it is and extract the information you need accordingly. But make sure that you also properly implement a fallback when a new - and yet unknown - `Task` type is introduced.

Comment: thank you, I'll give it a try. Will update soon