# Error handling for spring scheduled tasks

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

**spring-scheduler.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxxx.xxxx"/>

<bean id="xmlScheduledTask" class="com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"/>

<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="xmlScheduledTask" method="job" cron="*/10 * * * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

I am using the following code to load the configuration.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"resource", "unused" })  
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/spring-scheduler.xml");
```

Is there a way to check if my tasks are scheduled? Is there a way to throw error if there is no schedule or scheduled-tasks missing in the xml?

Comment: You can add a `@PostConstruct` in your xmlScheduledTask bean. Then you see that it is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am looking to check if the tasks are successfully scheduled. @PostConstruct or init-method will only tell us if bean is instantiated, right?

Comment: Why not add a logging statement to the task? Make it FINER or something so its not always getting logged.

Comment: This issue seems to be addressed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791853/how-are-spring-taskscheduled-objects-represented-at-runtime

Comment: You can use @PostConstruct to add logging or any other activity you want (so my first comment was a bit to brief)